# Error : Ajax is Undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using the below code in a script tag to call one URL in the background.

```
var request = new Ajax.Request(logoffURL, {method : 'post'});
```

But I am getting script error `Ajax is undefined`.

Do I need to include any external scripts?

Answer (score 2):

That code uses [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/). If you want to use that code, you'll need to include Prototype into your page. For example, using Google's CDN:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to include some external script ([jQuery](http://jquery.com/), for instance) and learn how to do ajax calls there. There is no Ajax object in browser, but there is XMLHTTPRequest. But again - you must learn how to use it first.  For instance - [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html) is how you can use XMLHTTPRequest

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good place to start:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

As the example shows, you can do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: logoffURL,
  context: document.body
}).done(function() { 
  alert("DONE");
});
```

I recommend using a CDN to reference jquery:

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery